# interfaceで定義したメソッドを、abstractでさらに継承先クラスに実装を強制させる書き方はやっていいのか

Tags: c#

下記コードのようにインタフェースAを継承した抽象クラスBを実装しています。
抽象クラスBではインタフェースAで実装を強制されているMethodAを実装しなければいけません。
ですが、MethodAの実装をabstructで自身を継承したクラスにさらに強制させています。
このような書き方はC#の言語仕様上よいものなのでしょうか。

```
public interface A
{
    int MethodA();
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public abstract int MethodA();
}

public class C : B
{
    public override int MethodA()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: 「言語仕様上よい」というのは、言語仕様で許されているかという意味でしょうか？

Comment: やっちゃダメかもと思った理由も気になります。社内で人に教える際の参考になるのでよかったらそこも教えていただければ。

Comment: >nekketsuuuさん　その通りです。言語仕様で許されているか、という意味で質問しました。コンパイルは通るのですが、このような書き方をした事がないのもあり質問しました。

Comment: >Rippleさん　まず、私がC#のinterfaceとabstructの違いを完全には理解出来ていないことが、この質問をした原因だと考えます。例で示したインターフェースAは、外部に公開する用としてメソッドAを定義しました。そして設計中に、間に抽象クラスを挟んだ三段構成にしないと都合が悪いことがありました。そこで、インターフェースの実装を孫の実装クラスCに強制させるのはいいのかと疑問に思い質問しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題ありません。C#言語リファレンスの[abstract](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract)にそのままズバリ例として挙げられています。

> インターフェイスを実装する抽象クラスで、インターフェイス メソッドを抽象メソッドにマップすることもできます。 次に例を示します。
>
> ```
> interface I
> {
>     void M();
> }
> abstract class C : I
> {
>     public abstract void M();
> }
> ```

Comment: インターフェースのメソッドを、抽象メソッドでさらに実装を実装クラスに強制させて良いのですね。またこの行為をマップというのですね。ありがとうございました勉強になります。